# how to show only errors with jshint

Tags: javascript, jshint

I am using JSHint for the static code analysis of my javascript files. I have configured the .jshintrc
file for that.

The question I have is that :

Is there a way in which we can configure jshint to **show only errors and no warnings.**

I know that we can do that by the warning code, but can we do that for all the warnings together?

Or Is there a way in which we can **classify errors and warnings?**

I am running jshint as a grunt task using the command **grunt jshint**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to enable jshint's --verbose option, which shows the error or warning code (e.g. E020 for Expected '}' to match '{' or W110 for Mixed double and single quotes), then grep for errors only:

jshint --verbose test.js | grep -E E[0-9]+.$

Comment: thanks. But I want to ask one more thing whether we can do this together for all the files in my project. I am running jshint as a grunt task, so is there a way so that when grunt runs the jshint task for all the files it shows only errors like in your answer it is doing for one file.